# combobox fill from another combobox selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, combobox

```
  Protected Sub rcmbDatabaselist_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles rcmbDatabaselist.SelectedIndexChanged
                Try
                    Dim strDestinationConnString As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=" & rcmbDatabaselist.SelectedValue & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=ssmits"
                    ViewState("strSyncDestinationConnString") = strDestinationConnString

                    Call getDestinationTableList()
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End Sub
            Protected Sub rcmbTableList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles rcmbTableList.SelectedIndexChanged
                Try
                    Call getDestinationClmList(rcmbTableList.SelectedValue)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End Sub
```

above 2 is event 
and below code is function how to fill in web.

Auto post back is true.
no error given when I debug.

Comment: it is in VB or C#?

Comment: And what is your question ? What is your problem ? What output does that code give you ? Please take some time to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can help you better.